# Html form to get response in php based on a rule (if)

Tags: php, html, forms, post, count

My form has several fields and three of them has select options with digits from 1 to 5.

Lets say that i have the below selectors:

```
$Cake= intval($_POST["Cake"]);
$Candy= intval($_POST["Candy"]);
$Box= intval($_POST["Box"]);
```

So how can i make a count fo the above field value and return an response as below:

```
//Box has 1 selected and Cake has 2 selected

    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));

//Box has 2 selected and Cake has 3 selected and Candy has 1 selected

    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Candy"));
```

And so on.

I know that i need to make  count formula and a if rule as below ( its not correct bu i eneter it to show some of what i need to do )

```
  if ( count($Box) == 2 count($Cake) == 4)
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
    array_push($box,array("paxType" => "Cake"), array("paxType" => "Cake"));
```

Each box must contain 2 cakes and 2 candies maximum.
Ex1

- Search : BOX ->2 ; Cake ->4
- Result: BOX(1) ->2 Cakes; BOX(2) -> 2
  Cakes;

Ex2

- Search : BOX ->2 ; Cake ->4 ; Candy ->1

  - Result: BOX(1) ->2 Cakes; BOX(2) -> 2 Cakes and Candy ->2;

How can i get this make working?
Thanks alot for your time and have a Happy New Year.

Comment: Shouldn't you use == instead of a single = in the comparison operation? Please refer to this link for more information: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Your if statement also is missing a logic operator between your two count tests.  I can't figure out exactly what you are trying to accomplish...but you need an `&&` or an `||` between the two.  Beyond that, please edit to explain what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use == instead of = to compare  and also you need to add an AND
like below

```
  if ( (count($Box) == 2) and (count($Cake) == 4) )
```

Comment: and should i use an for expression before this ?

Comment: no just try using it like this and tell me if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using this code  , please try it and let me know if you  have any concerns

```
$Cake_count= intval($_POST["Cake"]);
$Candy_count= intval($_POST["Candy"]);
$Box_count= intval($_POST["Box"]);

$box_array = array();
for($i=0;$i<$Box_count;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<$Cake_count;$j++)
    {
        $box_array[$i][] = array("paxType" => "Cake");
    }  

    for($k=0;$k<$Candy_count;$k++)
    {
        $box_array[$i][] = array("paxType" => "Candy");
    }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it work somehow. If i eneter 2 boxes and 3 cakes, i get the response with 2 boxes and each box contain 3 cakes

Comment: No.If i select 2 boxes and 3 cakes, i need to get the result with : 1st box contain 2 cakes and 2nd box contain 1 cake. So no more than 3 cakes and 2 candies for each box and

Comment: i have added some info on the answer, please check.